# Isometric embedding for manifolds with conical singularities?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

**Motivation:** 
In the 2+1 dimensional gravity theory, solutions of Einstein equation are locally with constant curvature except at the locus of sources. In [this paper](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/gthpub/Deser_Jack_tH_ThreeD_Grav_1984.pdf)<sup>1</sup> the authors investigate solutions with multi-point mass sources and it turns out that the solution admits a foliation, whose leaves are spacelike (means just Riemannian 2-manifolds) and with equal number of conical singularities.
**Example:** 
For n=1, the space metric is $dr^2+a^2r^2d\phi^2$, where $\alpha$ is a constant relating mass, and is isometrical to a conic in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
**Question1:** 
For n=2, the space can be constructed in the following way, [see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35XrH.png). Now intuitively it cannot be isometrically embedded into $\mathbb{R}^3$ if we do this like example1 for the line linking the two point mass is not smooth. 
Is it true? If not, what's the general procedure for $n>=2$?
Furthermore, are there works on isometric embedding for manifolds with conical singularities?
disclaim: My major is physics and I'm not sure whether it is proper to post the question here.... Any answer is welcomed:)

<sup>1</sup>S. Deser, R. Jackiw, G. Hooft: *Three-dimensional Einstein gravity: dynamics of flat space*, Annals of Physics 152, 220-235 (1984)

Comment: When you say "is not smooth", I get the impression that you want to realize these conical singularities as smooth surfaces in Euclidean space. That is impossible, as the cone angles are intrinsic metric structures which do not disappear under any local isometry. But of course, there are singular cones (at ice cream shops) in Euclidean space.

Comment: @BenMcKay No, the conical points are not belonging to the manifold (if you like, you can add it artificially). "is not smooth" means that the locus of the line linking these two points, if embedding it just like the way we do the papercraft for the n=1 case, will be non smooth. Imagine that you bite off the tip of an ice cream, then the left cannot be closed up smoothly.

Comment: Why is the line linking the two point masses not smooth intuitively? (I am missing your intuition; can you explain a bit more?)